Estimator of Poisson Distribution parameter
I had a doubt regarding the Properties of an Estimator specifically in the case of Poisson Distribution with parameter $\lambda$. I know $\mu=\lambda$ and $\sigma^2=\lambda$. Further, $\overline{X}$ is Unbiased, Consistent, MLE of $\lambda$, $S^2$ is Unbiased and Consistent for $\sigma^2=\lambda$. So if I wanted to know the Unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2=\lambda$, Can I use $\overline{X}$ as the Unbiased estimate for $\sigma^2=\lambda$ because $\mu=\sigma^2=\lambda$. Similarly can I use $\overline{X}$ as the Consistent estimator for $\sigma^2$, by the same argument that $\mu=\sigma^2$

So, what is exactly your question?

Can I use $\overline{X}$ as the estimator $\sigma^2$

Since $\lambda=\sigma^2=Var(X_i)$, and $\bar X$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$, which is also unbiased, you can (and really should) use it.
